# Angular Injected service is not being assigned to object instance

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using Angular6 and I have this:

```
'use strict';

import {ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MainService} from "./services/main.service";
import {AppService} from "../../app.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css'],
  providers: [MainService]
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {


  ms: MainService;

  constructor(
    ms: MainService,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onChange(val: string){
    console.log('here is the dropdown change:', val);
    this.ms.updateRoutes();
  }


}
```

unfortunately when I call this.ms.updateRoutes(), I get this error:

> MainComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'updateRoutes' of undefined
>       at MainComponent.onChange (main.component.ts:31)
>       at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (MainComponent.html:4)

I was under the impression that I didn't have to call

```
this.ms = ms;
```

in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
constructor(
  ms: MainService,
  private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
) {
```

to

```
constructor(
  public ms: MainService,
  private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
) {
```

this tells the TypeScript compiler that you want the `ms` to be automatically made a class variable.

Comment: yeah that's weird that the public/private TS keyword is necessary for the injection to work, I wonder how that works

Comment: The TS Compiler internally converts the `public ms: MainService` to `this.ms = _ms`